# How to have combination of one column in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this sqlite column:

```
USA
Russia
Japan
```

and I need have two columns like this:

```
USA Russia
USA Japan
Russia USA
Russia Japan
Japan USA
Japan Russia
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

Just join

```
select  t1.country, t2.country
from myTable as t1
join myTable as t2 on t1.country != t2.country
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a self join of the table based on the inequality of the columns:

```
SELECT t1.col AS column1, 
       t2.col AS column2
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.col <> t1.col;
```

Comment: "Combinations are done with cross joins." ... or inner joins, as it were. :) Interesting side point would be the question whether this and the cross join optimize into the same query plan.

Comment: ...just checked, they do.

Comment: @Tomalak from https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html: "The "CROSS JOIN" join operator produces the same result as the "INNER JOIN", "JOIN" and "," operators, but is handled differently by the query optimizer in that **it prevents the query optimizer from reordering the tables in the join**. An application programmer can use the CROSS JOIN operator to directly influence the algorithm that is chosen to implement the SELECT statement."

Comment: @Tomalak also: "Avoid using CROSS JOIN except in specific situations where manual control of the query optimizer is desired. Avoid using CROSS JOIN early in the development of an application as doing so is a premature optimization. The special handling of CROSS JOIN is an SQLite-specific feature and is not a part of standard SQL." So, I would use an INNER JOIN if I can avoid a CROSS JOIN.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. I'll remove my answer, then. I've had some suspicion into this direction ("cross join potentially faster under very specific circumstances") but the documentation is pretty clear that it should be avoided until those very specific circumstances arise.

Comment: @Tomalak in this particular case where the order of the joins is not important since it is a self join I believe the query plan would be the same. But in general I tend to use INNER joins.